# Cannot find the user 'database_principal', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a Notification Service in SQL Server 2008 R2.

But when i am running this command  `GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO database_principal`. I am getting below Error :

**Cannot find the user 'database_principal', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

Can Any one help me on this , what iam doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you determine whether or not the user exists yet?

Comment: Are you logged in as sa? Does the user you're logged in as have system admin or security admin privileges? If yes to both, then you should be able to determine easily if the database user 'database_principal' exists.